# awk code to get specific lines in a file

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file Query.txt with data like this:

```
  # Query: Name_ID
  # 2 hits found****
    # Query: Name_ID
    # 20 hits found
    # Query: Name_ID
    # 0 hits found
```

when I awk it or grep it for a pattern  I get output as follows:

```
grep "0 hits found" Query.txt | head
 # 20 hits found
 # 0 hits found
 # 140 hits found
 # 70 hits found
```

Two questions:
How do I specifically get just the "0 hits found" and not the 20 or 140 or 70?
second, How do I create another file Query2.txt with format like below using AWK ??

```
# Query: Name_ID  # 2 hits found
# Query: Name_ID  # 20 hits found
# Query: Name_ID  # 0 hits found
```

Answer (score 5):

To get only lines with `0 hits found` try to match that exactly string but without a digit just before the zero:

```
awk '$0 ~ /[^[:digit:]]0 hits found/' infile
```

Assuming a test input file (`infile`) like:

```
# Query: Name_ID1
# 2 hits found
# Query: Name_ID2
# 20 hits found
# Query: Name_ID3
# 0 hits found
# Query: Name_ID4
# 140 hits found
# Query: Name_ID5
# 0 hits found
# Query: Name_ID6
# 60 hits found
```

It yields:

```
# 0 hits found
# 0 hits found
```

For second question, use `getline` to read odd lines and print both at same time, like:

```
awk '{ getline hits_line; printf "%s %s\n", $0, hits_line }' infile
```

Using same test file as before, it yields:

```
# Query: Name_ID1 # 2 hits found
# Query: Name_ID2 # 20 hits found
# Query: Name_ID3 # 0 hits found
# Query: Name_ID4 # 140 hits found
# Query: Name_ID5 # 0 hits found
# Query: Name_ID6 # 60 hits found
```

---

An as extra, I like to try this kind of tasks using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) too, so here a solution with it:

Content of `script.vim`:

```
set backup
for n in range( 1, line('$') / 2 )
        execute "normal Jj"
endfor
saveas! Query2.txt
q!
```

Run it like:

```
vim -S script.vim infile
```

That will generate a `Query2.txt` file with content:

```
# Query: Name_ID1 # 2 hits found
# Query: Name_ID2 # 20 hits found
# Query: Name_ID3 # 0 hits found
# Query: Name_ID4 # 140 hits found
# Query: Name_ID5 # 0 hits found
# Query: Name_ID6 # 60 hits found
```

Comment: +1 @Birei, vim scripting looks pretty cool. Any book you'd like to recommend?

Comment: @Jaypal: Hi Jaypal. The documentation of `vim` is probably one of the best for a programming tool that I've ever read. Besides of that, two links, the [vim tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) and [a book of vimscript](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/)

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU sed

```
sed '/\s0/!d' file
```

(why "hits found" ?)

```
awk '/\y0/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a word boundary before the 0:

```
grep '\<0 hits found' Query.txt
```

---

You can achieve the 2nd part with

```
paste - - < Query.txt
```

Basically, this concatenates every 2 lines from a file.

Comment: Looks like he wants `-B1` to get the name too.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it with `sed`

```
sed -n 'N;/\<0 hits/{s/\n/ /;P}' Query.txt
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat Query.txt
# Query: Name_ID
# 2 hits found****
# Query: Name_ID
# 20 hits found
# Query: Name_ID
# 0 hits found

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed -n 'N;/\<0 hits/{s/\n/ /;P}' Query.txt
# Query: Name_ID # 0 hits found
```